# PHP remove apostrophe with preg replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove apostrophe from a title.
I use the title to create link with it but for example: "Ender's game" is kinda ruining the hole thing.

so I have this code: 
`$movie_title2 = preg_replace('/\s+/','-', $movie_title2);`

I did some research but for me the hole preg replace thing is foggy.
can please someone add the apostrophe removal in my code and maybe explain in a few words how it works?

Comment: Why preg replace? Use: str_replace("'","", $string);

Comment: because i already use it to remove spaces and add " - "

Comment: anyway, that did the trick :) thanks. make your answer formal so i can reward it please.

Comment: You can do multiple str_replace, for instance you can use an array of characters to be replaced like: str_replace($special_array," ", $actual_string);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why preg replace? Use: `str_replace("'","", $string);`